# C# Operator overloading ==

Tags: c#, operator-overloading

I am trying to overload the == operator but I am having the following error:

> Overloadable unary operator expected

Here is my code

```
  public bool operator == (MyClass nm1)
  {
       return true;
  }

  public bool operator != (MyClass m2)
  {
       return true;
  }
```

I followed the [msdn note](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8edha89s(VS.71).aspx) but still getting the same error

Comment: Operator methods are static. That means `==` and `!=` have 2 operands. Click the 'Operator Overloading Tutorial' link on that same page.

Comment: `public static bool operator == (MyClass m1, MyClass m2)`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you overload `operator ==` you should do it in a `static` method that takes two instances as parameters:

```
public static bool operator == (MyClass leftSide, MyClass rightSide) {
     return true;
}

public static bool operator != (MyClass leftSide, MyClass rightSide) {
     return !(leftSide == rightSide);
}
```

`static` context makes the code for your operator feel more "symmetric", in the sense that the code performing the comparison does not belong to a left instance or to the right instance.

In addition, `static` makes it impossible to "virtualize" the operator (you could still do it inside the implementation by calling a virtual function, but then you have to do it explicitly).

Comment: ohh I see .. will the first parameter be the left operand ?

Comment: @Kasparov92 Yes, the first operand is the left side, and the second operand is the right side.

Comment: @Kasparov92 Yes, but the order shouldn't matter since equality should be symmetric.

Comment: I dont understand this [static context makes the code for your operator feel more "symmetric".]

Comment: I think of it more logically without being static

Comment: @Kasparov92 It's static because it doesn't apply to a specific instance.

Comment: `+` must be `static` as well, but it allows an unary overload and a binary overload. They are called like this: `var resultFromUn = +arg; var resultFromBi = arg0 + arg1;`

Answer (score 3):

You need `static`, and you need *two* parameters, not just one.

`==` and `!=` are always *binary* operators (two arguments), not *unary* (one argument).

Answer (score 2):

As you can see in the [MSDN tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288467(v=vs.71).aspx) these are *binary* operators and thus they need two arguments. The operators should also be **static** as they will be part of the class and not the instance. See [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8edha89s.aspx) & [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/452727/A-Beginners-Tutorial-on-Operator-Overloading-in-Cs).

```
public static bool operator == (MyClass nm1, MyClass mn2)
{
   return true;
}

public static bool operator != (MyClass m1, MyClass m2)
{
   return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

the correct signature is:

```
public static bool operator ==(MyClass nm1, MyClass other)
{

}

public static bool operator !=(MyClass nm1, MyClass other)
{

}
```

The second parameter doesn't necessarily have to be of type `MyClass` though - but at least one of them must be.

Answer (score 0):

```
  public static bool operator == (MyClass m1, MyClass m2)
  {
       return true;
  }

  public static bool operator != (MyClass m1, MyClass m2)
  {
       return true;
  }
```